# Exchange EWS properties: IsOnlineMeeting OnlineMeetingSettings

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, skype

we are developing the application and one of its task is create a meeting and I would like to ask if somebody knows something more about EWS property *IsOnlineMeeting*.

Does anybody know how to handle these properties if we want to create the Skype meeting (online)? Should we fill mentioned properties?

**What is tested and investigated already:**

MS documentation on [IsOnlineMeeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.isonlinemeeting(v=exchg.80).aspx) and [OnlineMeetingSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.onlinemeetingsettings(v=exchg.80).aspx)

created a meeting (and added Skype meeting) through MS Outlook and used EWS editor to check its property

[image]

Unfortunately there is only OnlineMeetingSettings property with not very much saying value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question was answered here: [Using Microsoft's EWS to create online Lync/Skype meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503059/using-microsofts-ews-to-create-online-lync-skype-meeting)

filling UC properties the `IsOnlineMeeting` will be filled up automatically.