# Using Microsoft's EWS to create online Lync/Skype meeting

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices, skype, lync

Anybody knows how to create meeting request with online conference(Lync/Skype) using EWS?

So my approach is first getting an online and regular meeting created via Outlook and then simulate the creation of event with the same property.

Here is my code snippet for getting the meeting (`calendarView` is already initialized with start date, end date etc.):

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedOnlineMeetingProperty =
                new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(new Guid("{00062008-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}"), 34112,
                    MapiPropertyType.Integer);

var properties = new PropertySet(
            ItemSchema.Id,
            AppointmentSchema.ICalUid,
            ItemSchema.Subject,
            AppointmentSchema.Start,
            AppointmentSchema.End,
            AppointmentSchema.Organizer,
            AppointmentSchema.Location,
            AppointmentSchema.LegacyFreeBusyStatus,
            AppointmentSchema.IsCancelled,
            AppointmentSchema.ICalRecurrenceId,
            AppointmentSchema.MyResponseType, // Mandatory Meeting.MyResponseType can be retrieved without a search in the participant list
            ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime,
            AppointmentSchema.IsOnlineMeeting,
            AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting,
            ItemSchema.DisplayTo) { };

 properties.Add(extendedOnlineMeetingProperty);


var activeResults = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendarView).ToList();
    if (activeResults.Count > 0)
    {
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(activeResults, properties);
    }
```

I got the property `IsOnlineMeeting` with the correct bool value (tested -
 created online and regular meeting with Outlook) in variable `activeResults` but I do not understand where to get conference link and other Lync/Skype properties needed for joining a conference.

Also I am not sure where and how to assign the values of Lync/Skype conference URL and other properties.

Sometimes I ask myself if it's worth it to developed some app based on MS products since their documentation suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one week of cursing MS I have found a solution. Using the tool MFCMAPI you can check what property and their values your item in mailbox have.

1. download the program [link](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi)
2. build and run it
3. Session - Logon - choose your mail profile - pick the mailbox and double click
4. actions - open special folder - calendar - double click on calendar
5. open the item with online S4B/Lync conference
6. the UC* properties are the one I was looking for.

If you open the property you can see something like this on the top:

```
ag: 0x8096001E
Type: PT_STRING8
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/UCMeetingSetting
Named Prop Name: UCMeetingSetting
Named Prop Guid: {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} = PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS
```

So my definition of the extended property was wrong. It is not only one property but actually you need all 7 of them.

So the definition should be:

```
private static ExtendedPropertyDefinition CreateOnlineMeetingProperty()
        {
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedUCMeetingSetting =
                new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(new Guid("{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"), "UCMeetingSetting",
                    MapiPropertyType.String);

            return extendedUCMeetingSetting;
        }
```

With the correct extended definition you can get the values from the item easily.

1. accessing the `Value` of `ExtendedProperties`
2. Calling `TryGetProperty`

> ```
> var activeResults = service.FindAppointments(new
> FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, resource.Email),calendarView).ToList();
>
> service.LoadPropertiesForItems(activeResults, properties);
>
> foreach (Appointment result in activeResults)
> {
> // 1.
> var b = result.ExtendedProperties[1].Value;
> // 2.
> string UCMeetingSetting;
> result.TryGetProperty(extendedUCMeetingSetting, out UCMeetingSetting);
> }
> ```

using steps above you can get whatever extended property you want, not only Unified Communications (UC) properties.

Comment: Could you please help  me out with this? How can I add a Skype meeting link to a new meeting invite that I create using EWS?

Comment: Hi @Ian post a question with more info and I or others will try to help.

Comment: Well there are many questions regarding this topic on StackOverflow. However, I felt this is a possible solution for my problem. Basically I want to create a skype link and add it to an Outlook meeting. I did a research on this and see that we need to use other apis to do this.

Comment: yes, you need to call LWS (Lync Web Services) to get the meeting info and then you can attach it to body of meeting and use EWS to create it

Comment: That is where I am stuck, don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to have this working (almost!) by setting just one of the extended properties:

```
appointment.SetExtendedProperty(
                new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
                    new Guid("00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
                    "OnlineMeetingExternalLink",
                    MapiPropertyType.String
                    ),
                skypeMeeting.JoinUrl
                );
```

I say almost because the appointment doesn't look exactly like a Skype meeting when you open it in Outlook: doesn't have the footer will the Join link and phone number etc.
Maybe there are other differences, but for now we see it in Skype for business with the Join button and also we see the it in the Outlook reminder with the Join button.
As a workaround, we have to hard-code the body content of the appointment.
Also conference ID, can be taken using UCWA 2.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/myonlinemeetings_ref)

We used UCWA 2.0 to create the Skype conference call and attached it to the EWS appointment object.